# What is a shot?

Tags: espresso, terminology

I have visited Starbucks lots of times for their delicious coffee. As I stand in line, I hear people order coffee with like extra ***shots***. I tried searching up what it means but to no avail.  Here's an example of what I hear people say:

> I would like some coffee with two extra shots please!

What does the word "shot" mean in the coffee language? Yes, I have looked in the dictionary but no help was given.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are referring to a "shot" of espresso.  The [Italian standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso#Brewing) are that it is a volume of 25 mL  plus or minus ten percent.  Additional shots in a drink indicate more espresso flavor and a higher caffeine content.

Comment: +1 I should have guessed this was based on a metric measure.

Answer (score 9):

A "shot" in this context usually means one ounce, or so, of espresso. So a cup of coffee with two extra shots would be a cup of coffee with approximately two ounces of espresso added.

Answer (score 0):

[In Italian](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13527/3378) a "shot" is called a "little cup" (*tazzina*; [*tazza*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tazza) = 50 mL cup). *Espresso* means fast, because it's made quickly.

According to p. 4 of the [*Certified Italian Espresso and Cappuccino*](http://www.inei.coffee/files/File/istituzionale_inei_hq_en.pdf) guide by the [National Italian Espresso Institute (*Istituto Nazionale Espresso Italiano*)](http://www.inei.coffee/en), a Certified Italian Espresso shot has these parameters:

```
Necessary portion of ground coffee              7 g ± 0,5
Exit temperature of water from the unit         88°C ± 2°C
Temperature of the drink in the cup             67°C ± 3°C
Entry water pressure                            9 bar ± 1
Percolation time                                25 seconds ± 5 seconds
Viscosity at 45°C                               > 1,5 mPa s
Total fat                                       > 2 mg/ml
Caffeine                                        < 100 mg/cup
Millilitres in the cup (including froth)        25 ml ± 2,5
```